# Remove big gap between an object and a punctuation

Tags: microsoft-word

In MS word, there will not be any gap between a word and a punctuation mark, using the 'justify' alignment option, as shown in Line 6 in the figure below. It seems the punctuation is always bound together with the word that it follows. However, there can be a big automatic gap between an object (e.g., an equation) and the punctuation, as shown in Line 2. Is there a way to bind the object with the punctuation so that there will not be any gap inserted between them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the case of specifically an equation object, one solution would be to include the punctuation within the equation. To make the punctuation appear as normal text, you can go to the `Equation` tab when you have your equation object selected and select `Normal Text` before typing the punctuation into the equation.

However, in general, there isn't really an option for aligning the punctuation to be coupled with the object that preceded it.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Mathtype instead of the equation editor in MS. As you said, I can insert the punctuation as part of the equation if MS doesn't provide an option to reduce the gap.